# How to bootstrap confidence intervals and apply to geom_errorbar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I have calculated a list of 95% confidence intervals (ci) for 12 bars (means) using facet_grid plots in ggplot2:

```
ci <- c(0.17360519, 0.08659052, 0.19434605, 0.20922361, 0.06032738, 0.17054205,
        0.28033997, 0.18371310, 0.11388905, 0.24240948, 0.04037120, 0.19849716)
```

I can plot these confidence intervals using this code:

```
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Prob-ci, ymax=Prob+ci),
            width=.1, # Width of the error bars
            position=position_dodge(.09))
```

where 'Prob' is the mean on the y-axis.

My question is: How do I plot these confidence intervals after I've bootstrapped them using library(boot)?

For example, after bootstrapping as follows:

```
mean.boot <- function(x,ind)
{
return(c(mean(x[ind]),var(x[ind])/length(ind)))
}
out <- boot(ci,mean.boot,100000)
```

when this is the output:

```
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 100000 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = out)

Intervals : 
Level      Normal              Basic             Studentized     
95%   ( 0.1232,  0.2025 )   ( 0.1239,  0.2032 )   ( 0.1099,  0.2062 )  

Level     Percentile            BCa          
95%   ( 0.1224,  0.2017 )   ( 0.1208,  0.2003 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
```

Thanks for your time as always.

Comment: Are you asking how to extract the bootstrap estimates?  To get bootstrapped CIs I think you would pass the data to your bootstrap, not your previously calculated CIs.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "how to bootstrap confidence intervals". You use the bootstrap method to calculate CIs.

Comment: I'm apparently using boot incorrectly. I basically want to calculate CIs using the bootstrap method as @Roland articulated coherently. I'm guessing nongkrong has the right idea. I'll just have to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Study the examples in `help("stat_summary")`.